# How to trace a single process with 'sysdig'?

Tags: trace, strace, sysdig

How to trace a single process with `sysdig` ?

Something similar to `strace /bin/ls`

Answer (score 1):

`sysdig proc.name=ls`

sysdig doesn't have the concept of starting a child process, but you can instead use filters to reduce the output to include the events of a specific process.

Take a look at this page https://github.com/draios/sysdig/wiki/Sysdig%20User%20Guide#filtering for an overview of sysdig filters.